# Dynamics CRM 2011 Workflows business day calculation

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, workflow-services

I have a workflow that updates a field on a form.
On a creation or record it adds exactly "1 business day" to "created on" date and updates one field.

The problem is:
If it's before 9am or after 6 pm, that date is getting screwed up and gets calculated in a weird way
Examples:
created on               Updated field
12/03/2014 6:38am         13/03/2014 11:21am
12/03/2014 8:35am         13/03/2014 9:24am
12/03/2014 6:20pm         14/03/2014 10:20am

It looks like to do with opening hours settings, however.

The only settings that I know:
user working hours - it's all default -> all day
business closures -> nothing in there

are there any general business open hours setting?

***Where or what can I change to make it calculate correctly?***

Thank you

Comment: the workflow uses a custom workflow activity to add the business day?

Comment: There is no built-in way to add business days, only whole days. This must be some kind of custom workflow assembly. Can you provide a screenshot of the workflow editor steps to update the record?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up working hours by a particular User or Facility/Equipment. [Example here](http://www.magnetismsolutions.com.au/blog/paulnieuwelaar/2012/02/13/Scheduling_Work_Hours_and_Business_Closure_Dynamics_CRM_2011.aspx)
You might have to change the scope of the workflow to match the item that you chose (i.e. user).